How to remove all contacts from a list in sendgrid
I'm trying to make a function in typescript that removes or deletes all the contacts in a sendgrid list through their API. How can this be done?
I've tried getting a list of the contacts to delete by copying https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/contacts-api-lists/retrieve-all-recipients-on-a-list but the endpoints in "legacy marketing campaigns" seem to all return 403.

Does this answer your question?
